# Make Haar Functions periodic

Tags: matlab

I have implemented Haar Function in MATLAB based on formulas stated [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HaarFunction.html). However this formulas generate functions only between 0 and 1 (on [0..1] interval). I need to generate such functions periodically from -infinity to +infinity for instance with period = 1. It should depend on length of my time vector. For example if time vector on interval [0..10] I should generate Haar function vector on the same interval [0..10]. I hope you get a point. Here is my MATLAB code.

```
function [ f ] = haar(x)
%Haar function
%   x: time vector
vectorLength = length(x);
f = zeros(1, vectorLength);
for k = 1:vectorLength
    if (x(k) >= 0 && x(k) < 1/2)
        f(k) = 1;
    elseif (x(k) > 1/2 && x(k) <= 1)
        f(k) = -1;
    end;
end;
end
```

Comment: What if your vector length is odd?

Comment: I don't see any hard dependencies on vector length. Basically the same function pattern from 0 to 1 should be repeated periodically with period = 1. If vector length is higher then more times this pattern will be repeated.

Comment: How about multiplying the relevant part of code with `max(x)-min(x)`

Comment: This is more of a programming question than anything, but I just wanted to point out that it looks like the periodic extension of this wavelet would be nothing more than a square wave. You could use something like `f = 1 - 2 * (mod(x,1) >= 0.5);`.

Comment: This formula produces different results on [0..1] interval.

Comment: If everything is integer, why not just: `kron(ones(1,10),HAAR);` where `HAAR` is the [0,1] function.